# Including bib while comparing two latex file using latex diff

Tags: pdftex, latexdiff

I have two files `mainold.tex` and `mainnew.tex`. In both of them I have `refsold.bib` and `refsnew.bib` as bibliography. Now when I want to use `--flatten` while executing latexdiff command, I found an error saying the `refsold.aux` not found.

I tried to use TexShop and compile `mainold.tex`. But it is not generating `refsold.aux`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The question is tagged with `biblatex` but as far as I know `latexdiff` doesn't deal with `biblatex` bibliographies particularly well. Are you using `biblatex` (`\usepackage{biblatex}`) or classical BibTeX (`\bibliographystyle`)?

Comment: I don't know about TeXShop  but some editors try to clean up after the compile process so will delete `.aux` files and the like and some will use a 'build' folder to hide the auxiliary files elsewhere. Check the options of TeXshop for anything that might look like a clean-up or 'hide aux files' option.

Comment: I also notice the Overleaf tag: Does your question have anything to do with Overleaf specifically? In that case it may be useful to mention that more explicitly in the question body. If not, it may be better to remove the tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh one thing: When you compile your `.tex` file you will normally get an `.aux` with the same base name as the `.tex` file. So when you compile `mainold.tex` you get `mainold.aux`. You will in general not get an `.aux` file that is named after your `.bib` (so no `refsold.aux`).

Comment: I don't understand why latexdiff would want to include refsold.aux - this is not the normal way to flatten texts with bibliographies. It should simply look for mainold.bbl and mainnew.bbl file. To get help you need to construct an minimal example (MWE), and let us know the exact sequence of commands used.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! I have solved this issue. I generated the diff using latexdiff. later I uploaded it to the Overleaf and also the aggregation of two reference files (old and new). It works for me.